# Set ContextMenu items from a string list

Tags: powershell, contextmenu

Basically I'm trying to create a `ContextMenu` that shows a list of mounted network drive, so the user can click on one and access it.

The problem is : the list is not fix, but depend on a string list extracted from a `DataGrid`.

In my mind, I could just create the menu items by looping on that string list.

Here is the code sample :

```
$Main_Tool_Icon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms
[...]

# Add menu entries
$contextmenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu
$Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu = $contextmenu

foreach ($nameTag in $dataGrid[$DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME]){
    $menuEntry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $menuEntry.Text = $nameTag
    $Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($menuEntry)
}

# Add separator
$Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add('-')

# Last one to show main form
$displayMainform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
$displayMainform.Text = "Edit"
$Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add($displayMainform)
```

It appears that's wrong and only shows the separator and last "Edit" line.

Is there a way to populate a contextual menu with a list ?
Or I should look for a better way to do the job ?

**EDIT** @Mathias R. Jessen

You're right about `AddRange()`, it's just a mistake.

I can't show everything since it's quite big. I'll try to synthesize an answer properly.

- The data grid is created/populated by my script and is just a table of strings from a csv file.
- `$DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME = 'NAME'` it's one of constants defined for my datagrid headers.

Here is the setup

```
# set datagrid 
$dataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
[...]
$dataGrid.Columns.Add($DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME,'Name')
$dataGrid.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = $dataGrid.Columns[0].Name
```

Then some databinding

```
# initiate the data table
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[...]loop on csv file[...]
# bind data table to data grid
$dataGrid.DataSource = $table
```

**EDIT** @SantiagoSquarzon

You were right for pointing out `$dataGrid[$DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME]`. The syntax was bad and returned something null. Instead, I looped over the `$dataGrid.Rows` like so:

```
foreach ($row in $dataGrid.Rows){
    $nameTag = $row.Cells[$DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME].Value
    if ($nameTag -ne $null){
        $menuEntry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
        $menuEntry.Text = $nameTag
        $Main_Tool_Icon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange($menuEntry)
    }
}
```

Now I just have to figure out how to invoke there click event.

Comment: Why are you calling `AddRange()` when you only add 1 item at a time? use `Add()` instead. In any case, the first thing to check is whether `$dataGrid[$DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME]` actually resolves to a list of strings - can you show us where `$dataGrid` and `$DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME` are defined?

Comment: Your code works fine using a custom array instead of `$dataGrid[$DATAGRID_COLUMN_NAME]` and except that you're instantiating a `System.Windows.Forms` when it should be `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

Comment: Also right about the `Forms.Form`, it's a copy mistake.